# 支配人バッジの説明文が冗長

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, バッジ

### 不具合事象

[支配人バッジの説明文](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/steward)は現在、次のようになっています。「レビュー 1 種類につき何回でも獲得できます」と書かれているため、その後の「このバッジは何回も獲得できます。」は冗長に感じました。

> レビュータスクを 1,000 件以上完了しました。このバッジは、レビュー 1 種類につき何回でも獲得できます。. このバッジは何回も獲得できます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 提案

「このバッジは何回も獲得できます。」という文章自体を削除して以下のようにします。ja.traducir.win では文章自体の削除はできないようなので、メタにて提起しました。

> レビュータスクを 1,000 件以上完了しました。このバッジは、レビュー 1 種類につき何回でも獲得できます。

### 関連投稿

- [Steward badge can now be awarded multiple times -- backfill details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360279) ： このページで当該文章に関して言及されています

Comment: ご参考までに、現在 SO 英語版の Steward バッジの説明は日本語と同様冗長な文となっています : "Complete at least 1,000 review tasks. **This badge is awarded multiple times per review type. This badge can be awarded multiple times.**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

以下のように反映されたことを確認いたしました。

[image: steward]

https://ja.traducir.win/strings/14537 （ご提案くださいました文章を入力しました。）
https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15769 （冗長な部分を空欄にしました。）